# Crontab is not printing all the data

Tags: javascript, c, shell, ubuntu, cron

No printing data in the output file

Comment: Try catching the output and error as `2>&1` , may there is some error because of that lines are not in output

Answer (score 0):

Please check out for environment variables, this is a difference when we run a script in a shell or through cron. Please check if there is some dependency on some environment variable. This is just a thought, you need to figure out the difference in manual vs cron execution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to print the output in the format of string, e.g. '10.0.0.0' instead of 10.0.0.0.
2. Show us the code may be helpful.